# Global vector coordinates in local coordinate system of a pose bone

Tags: python, blender

I have a sphere with a location in global coordinates. I have a bone in pose mode.
I can see the local axes of the bone in the Layout.
I am wondering how I can get the coordinates of the sphere in the local coordinate system of my pose bone(using Python).
Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your code so we can better help with your question?

Comment: @Member2017 Not sure what to share, it's more of a conceptual question.